# C# 3D Chess Game

Tags: c#, 3d, chess

Hey so I want to create a 3D chess game (3D glass pieces), like the Chess game Vista provides, Chess Titans, but I'm not sure how to get started. I know I should probably use Blender for the modeling and Visual Studios for the programming. Can you provide links to comprehensive tutorials that can help me get started? Thank you

Comment: There are two potentially huge and very separate areas here.  3D graphics, and the chess engine.  You should probably approach each topic separately.

Comment: Do you want a pretty chess board or do you want a program that plays chess? Since you are focused on how the game pieces look it sounds like the former is more important.

Answer (score 5):

You should use Microsoft's XNA Game Studio:
http://creators.xna.com/en-US/

It's a great API actively maintained by Microsoft and there is a HUGE list of samples and tutorials to help you get started making 3D games right away.

Here's a link to a 3D Othello game written in C# and XNA:
http://creators.xna.com/en-US/minigame/minjie

Answer (score 2):

If you're just getting started, [Microsoft's XNA community](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/education/gettingstarted) site is a ***great*** place to get going.  They have free screencasts that literally start from 0 knowledge and build up from there.

If you've never made a game before, it's probably a good idea to start simple and work your way up.  I taught a High School computer class this past summer in which we first wrote the game as a text-based command line game, and then re-wrote it using XNA's game engine.  It seemed boring of course at first, but the students came to realize that the objects which represent the game on the back end are inevitably identical no matter what the graphics are like.

Coding simple first and worrying about graphics second is a good way to get your feet wet without becoming completely overwhelmed by learning tons of things at once.

Answer (score 0):

Why not start with creating a 3D board and get the AI logic done, with 2D chess pieces.

This way you can get most of the way on your game and then you can change the textures on the board, improve the chess pieces and better control how the light sources will work.

Answer (score 0):

Googled some resources for you:

[Creating an Interactive 3D World in C#.NET](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/graphics/article.php/c11375/)
[Games Programming in C# - Tutorials, Articles, Source code, FAQ, Discussions, Blogs](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Articles/ArticleListing.aspx?SectionID=1&SubSectionID=65)
[Creating an Interactive 3D world with C# and DirectX](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3582636/Creating-an-Interactive-3D-world-with-C-and-DirectX.htm)

Answer (score 0):

For the 3d part, check out unity 3d (http://unity3d.com/), the indy version is now free and support the C# language among others.